# How to build a QT Application efficently?

Tags: python, c++, qt

I am currently building a desktop software. As my graphical skills are limited, I chose **C++ QT** to make it fast and clean (On top of the .ui files, I coded **a lot** in .cpp files to modify the behaving of the windows, etc).

The application is supposed to be a graphical interface for a Python Web scraper using Selenium that I built earlier this year.

The deployment should be *cross-plateform* (Windows / MacOS) so the main goal is to make this project easy to compile and deploy in .exe / .app.
*I cannot use mac/windeployqt unfortunatly as I added many .cpp files to the project*.

My application is made of two parts :

- The python scraper
- The C++ QT GUI

But here is the problem, I don't know how to interconnect those two parts. I am facing a dilemma, with multiple possible outcomes :

- I rebuild the python scraper in C++ using QtWebDriver which is going to be a pain in the ...
- I use pyuic5 to translate my .ui files in .py and then I recode my .cpp files in .py, which may take a while and is not really convenient.
- I use QT Python script embedding to call my python scraper but I'll have more work to make it deployable and provide dependencies
- `rm -rf -no-preserve-root /`

Both parts of the software are already fully coded and functionnal.

The GUI is already deployable thanks to [appdmg](https://github.com/LinusU/node-appdmg)

Which solutions should I take to make this easily maintainable and deployable ? Which one would be considered *"best-practice"* in my case ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PythonQt](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/Examples.html)
( not to be confused with PyQt )

It should allow you to evaluate scripts such as your webscraper inside a C++ file.

You should then just be able to deploy as if were just C++ avoiding any python related headaches.

Comment: But my python scraper has many files / imports. PythonQt is just to evaluate some small scripts

Comment: You can evaluate python files too, not just one line scripts